Is there some mapping between Maven version and Maven compiler plugin version?
I know the version of Maven
How do I know the version of Maven compiler plugin if it's not explicitly specified?
I'm asking this since a TeamCity build failed. Maven can't find a DaggerXComponent class that Dagger should have generated. The module was built alright locally. The TeamCity Maven version is lower
I don't know the Maven compiler plugin version, though. It is important

If you are using a version of the maven-compiler-plugin lower than 3.5, add the dagger-compiler artifact with the provided scope

I didn't have that dependency locally and didn't push it to TeamCity
Dagger 2.51.1. Local Maven 3.9. TeamCity Maven 3.6. Java 8

First question: Why is is not defined in your pluginManagement?

There are multiple ways, the most direct is
mvn -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin help:describe

Which outputs (for my Example project configured to use 3.8.1)
[INFO] --- help:3.4.0:describe (default-cli) @ Example ---
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1

Name: Apache Maven Compiler Plugin
Description: The Compiler Plugin is used to compile the sources of your
  project.
Group Id: org.apache.maven.plugins
Artifact Id: maven-compiler-plugin
Version: 3.8.1
Goal Prefix: compiler

This plugin has 3 goals:

compiler:compile
  Description: Compiles application sources

compiler:help
  Description: Display help information on maven-compiler-plugin.
    Call mvn compiler:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=<goal-name> to display
    parameter details.

compiler:testCompile
  Description: Compiles application test sources.

For more information, run 'mvn help:describe [...] -Ddetail'

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.099 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-27T12:13:02-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------


Thank you! Are there mappings between Maven versions and Maven compiler versions (if not specified)?

@demavi No idea. And off-site resource requests are off-topic. This is how you can get the Maven compiler version for a given pom. Which is definitely more accurate. There might be a parent pom. So one could be specified somewhere you aren't looking.

You should always explicitly set versions of everything with maven. Your ide should be able to help you.
